# How to close react-select input when user clicks outside of the input?

Tags: react-select

I'm creating a select input using `react-select` version 1.1.0.

After I click the right-arrow to open the dropdown list, it doesn't close when I click elsewhere on the page.  I have to either select an element or click the arrow again to close the element.

How can I make the dropdown list close when the user clicks outside the select element?

https://codesandbox.io/s/nrmpvw6oll

Comment: Try upgrading the `react-select` to 1.2.0. That might fix your problem.